# How to perform group by, count and sum from list of object in single stream and store in another list of object?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get the group by, count and sum from list of the object using java stream and collection. I am not sure how do I achieve the desired result.

InputModel

```
String month;
BigDecimal salary;
String department;
String noOfEmp;
```

InputModel[(May,100,IT,10), (June,300,IT,7),(July,300,IT,7),(May,1000,HR,5), (June,300,HR,7),(July,600,HR,5)]

OutputModel

```
String month
BigDecimal salary
String noOfEmp
```

**Expected Output**
OutputModel[(May,1100,15),(June,600,14),(July,900,12)]

I tried below code but it returned group by and Count.

```
Map<String, Integer> result= inputModels.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(InputModel::getMonth,
            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(InputModel::getNoOfEmp)));
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What's the class that represents the InputModel/OutputModel?

Comment: Where is the ```getCount``` method? I do not see a field called ```count```.

Comment: @madplay Sorry for the typo :( its getNoOfEmp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that you have `OutputModel` class in place, this will solve your problem.

```
Collection<OutputModel> outputModels = inputModel.stream()
    .map(im -> new OutputModel(im.getMonth(), im.getSalary(), im.getNoOfEmp()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(OutputModel::getMonth, Function.identity(),
        (m1, m2) -> new OutputModel(m1.getMonth(), m1.getSalary().add(m2.getSalary()),
            String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(m1.getNoOfEmp()) + Integer.valueOf(m2.getNoOfEmp()))),
        LinkedHashMap::new))
    .values();
```

Word of caution: Better NOT to use Strings where other types are more appropriate. For an instance you should have used `int` to represent `noOfEmp` instead of a `String`. That would simplify the code while reducing the possibility of runtime errors due to spurious data. Moreover consider using `java.time.Month` enum to represent month of the year contrary to using String literals.

Here's the output,

> [{month=May, salary=1100, noOfEmp=15}, {month=June, salary=600,
>   noOfEmp=14}, {month=July, salary=900, noOfEmp=12}]

Comment: Thanks again, Now I am getting the result but It losing the month order??? Any suggestion??

Comment: I am able to make this is working with month order by using ,LinkedHashMap::new. Thanks

Comment: You have to pass `LinkedHashMap::new` to the `mapFactory` if you need to preserve the encountering order. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

you can combine `groupingBy` and `reducing`

```
Map<String, Optional<OutputModel>> outputModels = inputModel.stream()
            .map(ip -> new OutputModel(ip.getMonth(), ip.getSalary(), ip.getNoOfEmp()))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(OutputModel::getMonth, 
                           LinkedHashMap::new, 
                           Collectors.reducing(OutputModel::merge)));

//the following method goes into OutputModel
public static OutputModel merge(OutputModel o1, OutputModel o2) {
        return new OutputModel(o1.month, o1.salary.add(o1.salary), o1.noOfEmp + o2.noOfEmp);
}
```

I used `LinkedHashMap` so insert order will be preserved, also I've changed `noOfEmp` to `Integer`